# White screen after splash screen in Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run my android app with Android Studio in Emulator (Android API 23 - Android 6.0), the screen stay on white screen after the splashScreen.

I tried every solutions I can see on the web, but nothings for the moment...

It's a new blank app, I don't add new components or pages.

[White screen in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twCra.png)

If I launch the same app in other emulator (Android API 30 - Android 11), the app works :

[Emulator 2 work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL0Ps.png)

Any solutions for me please ? :)

Ionic info :

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.9
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.0.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.0.4
   @angular/cli                  : 12.0.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\dimit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v14.16.1 (C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v14\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.12
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Just FYI, you won't be able to publish apps on the Play Store if you target APIs lower than 29.

Answer (score 5):

After long moment of search, I found the solution.

In tsconfig.json file, replace target with "es5" :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: may i know what is causing this issue? when i changed the target to "es5" it worked for me too..

Comment: what's the magic btw? It worked for me too